# Why are designs not done with a perfectly aligned grid and layout?

Tags: sketch-app, page-layout, design-principles, grids, layout

Why do so many designs have the grid and layout misaligned:

[image]

Instead of having the Grid and Layout aligned:

[image]

The majority of projects I have downloaded from sketch resources website, don't even use a grid/layout, and if they do it is not aligned.

Comment: How do you know what grid scale they used?

Comment: How do we know without asking the developers of every misaligned project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "law" or "rule" which states a grid *must* be used or that everything *must* be perfectly aligned with other elements.

Paul Rand would have exploded if forced to stick to boring grids and perfect alignments.

But also, sometimes people are people and alignment errors can and do happen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your particular situation, but in general you also need to account for optical corrections to space things out evenly and this can in some cases break the grid. By the way there is also this book [https://www.amazon.com/Making-Breaking-Grid-Graphic-Workshop/dp/1592531253](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592531253)